# How do I draw custom "Callout Bubbles" (the place name transparent-gray overlay) in an iPhone application using non-google maps?

Tags: iphone, annotations, maps, overlay, markers

I'm building an iPhone application with a map inside (using route-me, not MapKit).

I have some markers on the map, and I want to have an overlay - similarly to the google maps one - that appears once you click a marker:
A black - a bit transparent - overlay, with a button inside, and a little triangle pointing to the marker the overlay is referencing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these things are called 'callout bubbles'. Apple has a [MapCallouts](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746) sample that shows you how to customize them.

Comment: I'm not using MapKit, I'm using route-me.  
The question is about a sample code that can draw such a thing on it's own, without any relation to which map library I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Read the quartz2d docu from Apple. They explain in detail how to create custom views.